# Plesk 10 Qmail issue

Tags: email

I had problem with a spamming domain and I am asked to delete files in some folders in var/qmail/queue but I accidentally deleted whole folders.

Now any domain can either get or send email, getting

554 mail server permanently rejected message (#5.3.0)

Is there any way to fix this beside using a backup?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall qmail

Or try to use this tool

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/mchk --help
```